# Auto sizing UILabel with SnapKit

Tags: swift, uiview, autolayout, uilabel, snapkit

Let's assume `CustomView's` size is 300x300. `iconImageView` has its size and assigned constraints. I do not know how long is going to be text in `UILabel` so I do not want to make constant size of `UILabel`. My goal is to pin left constraint to right side of the `iconImageView` and right to `customView`.

```
override func updateConstraints() {
    super.updateConstraints()

    iconImageView.snp.updateConstraints { (make) in
        make.left.equalTo(customView).offset(10)
        make.centerY.equalTo(customView)
        make.size.equalTo(CGSize(width: 40.0, height: 40.0))
    }

    nameLabel.snp.updateConstraints { (make) in
        make.right.equalTo(customView).offset(-10)
        make.left.equalTo(iconImageView.snp.right).offset(10)
        make.centerY.equalTo(customView)
    }
}
```

When I try this method I get error: `Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.` What's a proper way to do this?

Comment: hmmm... I just tried your code, and it worked fine. I'm assuming this code is in a `UIView` subclass? And *that* view has proper constraints relative to its SuperView? And `customView` has proper constraints to make it 300x300 and positioned inside that view?

Comment: This code is in UIView subclass, and it has proper constraints relative to superview. Error comes out when i slide to another ViewController because this view is part of UIPageViewController.

Comment: hmm... guess we'd need a little more information about when you're getting the error. You should first, though, read through the discussion about overriding `updateConstraints()` here (it might just give you the information you need to begin with): https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622512-updateconstraints

Answer (score 3):

Well, I suppose your subview don't know anything about top/bottom constrains which means the view don't know how to re-layout itself. Try this one:

```
override func updateConstraints() {
    super.updateConstraints()

    iconImageView.snp.updateConstraints { (make) in
        make.left.equalTo(customView).offset(10)
        make.centerY.equalTo(customView)

        // Also from my point of view this line \/ 
        // is not very readable
        //  make.size.equalTo(CGSize(width: 40.0, height: 40.0))
        // Changed to:
        make.width.height.equalTo(40.0)
    }

    nameLabel.snp.updateConstraints { (make) in
        make.right.equalTo(customView).offset(-10)
        make.left.equalTo(iconImageView.snp.right).offset(10)

        // Add:
        make.top.equalTo(customView.snp.top)
        make.bottom.equalTo(customView.snp.bottom)
    }
}
```

If you want to keep "default" height of your label (in case of empty strings etc.) you can add:

```
make.height.greaterThanOrEqual(40.0)
```

also autolayout and frames don't work well with each other, so you should layout your custom view in "updateConstraints" method, similar to this:

```
customView.snp.updateConstraints { (make) in 
     make.edges.equalTo(self)
}
```